# Registering Context Menu in WiX MSI Installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu something like the menu in 7-Zip using C#. How can I register the dll using WiX?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Step one is to learn how to do it by hand. This involves creating a Shell Extension, and [registering it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110). Per MSDN, you do this by [implementing IContextMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127443) and listing its CLSID in a subkey of the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*ProgID*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers. Additionally, after writing that registry key, you have to call [SHChangeNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118) with **SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED**, or reboot.

If your needs are simpler than the 7-zip case, you can likely just register a [Verb or File Association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175) instead.

Once you've done this, and tested it on your development machine, you're ready for step 2: make it part of your installer. If you're creating a verb or file association, that's possible with native Windows Installer tables, as exposed through the [ProgId](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/progid.html), [Extension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/extension.html), and [Verb](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/verb.html) elements. If you're registering a shell extension, I believe you have to create the registry keys directly through the [RegistryKey](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html) and [RegistryValue](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registryvalue.html) elements.

For more concrete examples of the WiX authoring, see the answers to [How to register file types/extensions with a WiX installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138550/how-to-register-file-types-extensions-with-a-wix-installer) and [How to associate application with existing file types using WiX installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772452/how-to-associate-application-with-existing-file-types-using-wix-installer)