# open a file and a .net application will recognize it?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to associate a file extension to the current executable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp)

I dont know how exactly to call this issue.

I am looking for a solution such as: my .net application will be automatically opened when a filetyle defined for that application is open.

For example: the filetype of that application has an extension xyz: hellothere.xyz

Whenever, the user opens the file with an extension "xyz" then that .net application will be opened. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file association can be created manually in Windows Folder Options. [This article](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/blog/net/programmatically-creating-windows-file-associations/) describes how to do it programmatically, for example with a registry file:

- Create a string key for your file extension in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` named `.xyz`.
- Set its value to the name of your file type, e.g., `XyzDocument`.
- Create a string key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XyzDocument\open\shell\command`.
- Set its value to `"path\to\your\program" "%1"` or similar, per your needs.

You can also do it from a batch script with `ftype` and `assoc`:

```
ftype XyzDocument="path\to\your\program" "%1"
assoc .xyz=XyzDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is "file association". The best place to create a file association for your application is in your installer. The exact process depends on what installer technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding issue but an OS configuration issue.

For windows, you need to setup a file extension association with your program.

See [this How to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
[How to change or select which program starts when you double-click a file in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859)

?

Comment: I would like to do it automatically without opening and selecting which application to run.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to register a filetype with your application. You can do this by right-clicking a file of that type, selecting `Open with`, and select your application.

**EDIT** 
Per your comment, devn, I see that you want to do this at install time. That being the case, you could use WiX to accomplish this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138550/how-to-register-file-types-extensions-with-a-wix-installer).

Comment: but I want to do it automatically. let's assume that a mp3 file, when I click on it, winamp will be opened. I dont know whether I can do this during the .NET setup process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file association during the installation. For a walkthrough of creating that, see the "Creating a File Association" section of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd.aspx) on creating that association during install.

Note: others have posted articles on how to do this manually, but I think you're mention of uses means you want to do this during setup.