# WIX file association side by side - default application

Tags: wix, windows-installer, file-association

Is there a way in WIX that allows me to specify that a certain application should be treated as the default one when the user double clicks on a file with a certain extension?

For example, let's say I have an application **A**, whose installer sets the following association:

```
  <ProgId Id="XYZFile" Description="App A file">
    <Extension Id="xyz" ContentType="application/text">
      <Verb Id="open" Command="Open" TargetFile="A.exe" Argument='"%1"' />
    </Extension>
  </ProgId>
```

And then I have application **B** that deals with the same extension and sets the following association:

```
  <ProgId Id="XYZFile" Description="App B file">
    <Extension Id="xyz" ContentType="application/text">
      <Verb Id="open" Command="Open" TargetFile="B.exe" Argument='"%1"' />
    </Extension>
  </ProgId>
```

Is there a way to make app **B** the default one for the file extension specified, in the following scenarios:

- User installs app **A**, which associates the extension `xyz` with app **A**, then installs app **B**. In this case the desired behaviour is for app **B** to launch when the user double clicks on the file.
- User installs app **B**, then installs app **A**. In this case the desired behaviour is for app **B** to launch when the user double clicks on the file. So installing app **A** does not overwrite the default file association.
- User uninstalls app **B**, file association defaults back to app **A**.
- User uninstalls app **A**, file association remains with app **B**.

I had several attempts at googling a similar requirement and solution, but so far haven't found a clear answer.

Comment: This is largely an anti-pattern of the technology - the difficulty of handling advanced file association issues - each install things it "owns" the association. Could you instead use the application itself on first launch to write the keys to the HKCU registry hive instead? **`HKCU\Software\Classes`** - just asking before writing up anything on that. There is also the **`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`** location (sub keys) which stores what application the user used from the ***"Open With"*** dialog. Not sure what takes precedence in what version of Windows.

Comment: [Reference material - learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro).

Comment: A similar (and very old) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138550/how-to-register-file-types-extensions-with-a-wix-installer